# Strange residues after separation of mesh

Tags: modeling

I have modelled this large building (see below). After joining all the elements of the building to one big mesh I separated a part of the building. In this building there are floors and these floors / planes are also separated now. But you see in the encircled area that somehow there are residues ( "borders" of those planes). What are those residues ? It looks like that these residues are the borders of those planes / floors ???

[image]

This is the blend file before separation

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think you were in face selection mode, and you have unconnected edges. That is what you are seeing now. Because the edges were not part of a face they will stay unselected when using face select mode.

PS You also have a LOT of duplicate vertices, 83,559 to be exact, Not related to this, but probably not going to help you.

To delete the unconnected edges, switch to edge select mode, and select one of the loose edges.
Then from the 3D view header *Select* > *Select Similar* > *Amount of Faces Around an Edge*, or just simply <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>. Now delete all the selected vertices with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*, or <kbd>Delete</kbd> > *Vertices*.

[image: animated gif - showing the select similar operator]

Comment: I will try your solution but how are these residues created ?

Comment: I dont know how you made the mesh, but probably at some point (maybe when you were making the window?) you just accidentally duplicated an edge. Then after applying all array and mirror modifiers, it  adds up to a lot of duplicated edges.

Comment: thanks. your solution works. !!! Also important that I know what was causing these problems

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong. When I do Shift G and delete the vertices also some holes in my mesh are created. So the residues are deleted but also some parts of the mesh that should be kept.

Comment: do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't know, in the file you uploaded first (large_city_building_003) it works for me. Are the meshed different in different versions of your file?

Comment: do you still have that file ? I think I have not

Comment: have you tried with the file I uploaded to Blend Exchange ?

Comment: Yes I do still have the file. I just tried separating a piece of your building from the new file, and it works as expected. The only pieces that remain in the hole are the floor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42452/discussion-between-old-man-and-david).